# Water heater power cable has changed color

Tags: safety, cables

Couple of years ago I've installed an electric water heater in my toilet room (a model similar to [this one](https://www.atlantic-comfort.com/Our-products/Water-heating/Electric-water-heaters/Vertigo-Steatite-Essential)). It's a kind of water heater that has a big tank of water with heating elements inside.

Recently I've noticed that the power cable which once was pure white is now having these regions of brownish rusty-looking color:

[image]

[image]

It's definitely not dust or grime as it can't be wiped off / removed, looks like the insulation material has changed color.

**What can be the reason for this? Is it dangerous, can it affect insulation properties?** It's quite possible to touch the cable when using the toilet.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: light PVC discolouration with heat is not a safety issue.  The specs indicate 5A and this photo  likes like the wire gauge is suitable.  If you feel the wire getting mildily warm , that is normal. Hot  would be a concern for the contacts that might oxidize at the screw terminal and if not fastened securely make that dark brown near the connection.

Comment: In places, like this, ammonia concentration in air higher then regular. Isolation is PVC, may be affected.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_water

and other articles discussing "hard water mineral deposits" I would verify that there are no symptoms of excess heat, bad insulation, or bad connections in the wire then I would consider whether the stain is "brown scale" (mineral deposit) caused by the evaporation and condensation of moisture in the surroundings.